# data bind to ngrepeat not updating when ajax successfully comes from server.

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to call a github api and plot the data using ng repeat. But Its the value is not updated when the data comes using AJAX.
What I am doing wrong

Here is my html part.

```
<div infinite-scroll='totalData.nextPage()' infinite-scroll-disabled='totalData.busy' infinite-scroll-distance='1' >
<div ng-repeat='item in totalData.items' >
  <span class='score'>{{item.owner.id}}</span>

</div>
<div ng-show='reddit.busy'>Loading data...</div>
```

here is my js part.

```
var app = angular.module('ngTableTutorial', ['infinite-scroll']);
   app.controller('tableController', function ($scope, $filter,Reddit) {
        $scope.totalData = new Reddit();

    });

    app.factory('Reddit', function($http) {
        var Reddit = function() {
            this.items = [];
            this.busy = false;
            this.after = 'https://api.github.com/repositories?since=862'+ "&jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK";
          };
          Reddit.prototype.nextPage = function() {
            if (this.busy) return;
            this.busy = true;

            var url = this.after+ "&jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK";
            $http.get(url).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            var regExp = /\<([^>]+)\>/;
            var test = regExp.exec(headers().link);
            console.log(test)
                console.log(data,headers().link)
                this.items.push(data)
                this.after = test[1];
                this.busy = false;
            }.bind(this));
          };

        return Reddit;
    });
```

Comment: Is it possible to provide working jsFiddle or plunker that reproduce the same issue?